# converting a nexus file to json format

Tags: json

so I'm creating a Web application (with a biological backround) with D3.js so it only takes .json files as entry data. A part of my Web application displays a phylogenic tree. The phylogenic data is already stored in a .nexus file.
My question is: is there a tool to convert a nexus file into a json format?? since the two formats have the same architecture: nodes and leefs..
here is a simplified example of my nexus file:

```
#NEXUS
BEGIN TREES;
  TREE tree1 = ((A,B),C);
END;
```

for a more complex tree here is a visulisation:
http://itol.embl.de/tree/4619365133443341495324227

Comment: Even http://www.cmpg.unibe.ch/software/PGDSpider/#Input_and_output_formats does not support JSON. I suppose http://www.kmeverson.org/blog/convert-among-alignment-file-formats-nexus-phylip-fasta-etc "custom script" section remains the only alternative.

Comment: If This can help anyone; I have found this tree:
[link](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/c034d66572fd6bd6815a)
the function **parseNewick** converts a **newick** format file into a json. the newick format is pretty similar to the nexus..

Comment: Interesting. You can add that as an answer (with a bit more detail on how you use that link)